# Fixing divs with position

Tags: css

How to set which div is over another by position fixed? 
If I have 3 divs and page is separated with those 3 divs I want to make them all fixed but I one left and right be over the center one I have photo example with two but it same question.
[Example one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWZGg.png)
[Example two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIAb.png)
With example one when I put img from behind as fixed img over message div...

Comment: use `display:table;float:right`

Comment: cannot work :/ it is just going over ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving them z-indexes.

Just add `z-index: (some number)`.

The element with a bigger index will be in front.

[Documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Rly man tnx but already i changed all css code so yea I wanted to stick images around main content and to follow page so i just put on start of code one img and on end other :D before that I wanted them yo be next to main content but now if my main content have width 500px and its centered can I do something as setting img like 100px from 50% of page or middle of page?